# In what way do Hund's rules explain that a configuration is not possible?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics

In this particular context, how were Hund's rules used to flat out eliminate these possible configurations for Silicon?

> SAQ: Apply Hund's rules to $\mathrm{3p^2}$ configuration (silicon).
> $$
> \ell_1=\ell_2=1\to L=0,1,2\ (S,P,D)\quad^1S, {}^1P, {}^1D,{}^3S, {}^3P, {}^3D
> \\s_1=s_2=\frac12\to S=0,1
> $$
> The ${}^3S$ and ${}^3D$ configurations are eliminated.

I thought Hund's rules were simply for finding the lowest energy states.